# Service Entrance Breakers Rain Shield

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, weather-resistant

This is our townhouse (5 house) service entrance. We only put plastic sheet above to partially cover it from rain, but when it is strong, the breakers got wet (this being going on for the past 20 years). Any idea what kind of glass or cover to put inside to prevent rain from wetting it (raining season coming in 2 months). We can't replace the panels because it would require so much city hall paperworks (even replacing a breaker needs city hall permit) and the neighbors won't cooperate putting up money for the repair or any power interruption.

[image]

Comment: What country is this?

Comment: Philippines.   (15 characters minimum)

Answer (score 5):

See the **gutter** above the meters?   Yeah?   The thing below the meters where the breakers are, *used to be a gutter just like that*.   It has completely rotted out.

Your best bet here is to fully enclose this area in a "shed" with a roof that will shed rain, solid sides, and doors that latch and seal.  You can put this together out of plywood, prime, paint and caulk it.  The weird cage around it - just like that, but with solid wood.

Comment: Another variant might be to use the existing cage as a frame, to support some exterior-rated plywood, or plastic panels.  Sealing the "doors"  might be the biggest challenge, along with getting a watertight flashing between the "roof" part and the building's wall.

Comment: Harper and Criggie, the power company reads the meters monthly for the past 20 years. All of our meters are read manually, not by remote. They can't shut them down by remote too. So I must put a fiberglass cover (or glass?) for the breakers and meters partially. Maybe glasses that like used for aquarium? or what plastic cover is easy to fabricate that I can put inside the grill cage?

Comment: There is a meter cover made specifically for that.

Comment: where to buy it?  you mean something that will just put it on without removing the breakers? any pictures? Remember the meters can't be shut down by remote. And the only time the power company would shut it down is after we have city hall permit for service entrance remodeling. Even just replacing a breaker is called remodeling and there are many steps. This is to ensure no one would just modify them at will.

Comment: The power company will lend you one for free when they pull the meter. If you need to get one on the sly, not sure.  It's not exactly a big-box store item.

Comment: I didn't mean meter cover.. I meant breaker covers. Do you know what kind of plastic or nonconductive material that one can build to cover the breakers without removing them? As I have said. We need city hall permits to remove all breaker and replace the panel but neighbors won't cooperate. So I'd just put a fabricable plastic cover. Any idea what kind of plastic one can fabricate for it? Something that can be bent and moulded?

Comment: I don't mean cover the breakers.  I mean cover the whole cabinet.  Replace that goofy cage thing with a wooden shed style thing maybe 1.3m wide by 2.5m tall and maybe 400mm deep , whatever is needed.

Comment: But as I have said. I can't cover the whole cabinet because the power company needs to take reading by manually looking at the meter and writing down the usage for billing each month. Do you mean in the US, they no longer do that and the power company can read the meter at remote? Here they can't do it. So the meters LCD must be seen and accessible so the utility man can see the reading and write it down every month. I always see them reading the meters. Hence the best is to just cover the breakers and partially the meters with some kind of moulded plastic. So I'm asking what kind of plastic?

Comment: I don't mean *entomb* it.  I mean make it with a big door on the front that opens, like a wardrobe or something.  With a latch so it stays shut and doesn't get rained on.